# How do i filter empty rows from a datatable without using a loop?

Tags: c#, datatable

I've scenario where the datatable may contain large number of rows. As a result i am not able to iterate and update the datatable using a loop.

I've tried the following code,

```
          from row in table.AsEnumerable()
          where table.Columns.Any(col => !row.IsNull(col))
          select row;
```

But i can't find definition for **Any()**. Is there any namespace i should use to get Any()?

Any body please tell me how to correct this or suggest any alternate solutions..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apart from having to use the `System.Linq` namespace you also need to make it aware of the element types. `DataTable.Columns` is not a generic collection (it implements only `IEnumerable` not `IEnumerable<T>`) and the compiler cannot infer the type. You need to do something like this:

```
from row in table.AsEnumerable()
where table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>.Any(col => !row.IsNull(col))
select row;
```

Comment: I think it'd be better to use `Cast<T>()` rather than `OfType<T>()`.  Cast just performs the cast.  OfType on the other hand will do additional filtering.  Everything in the `Columns` collection is known to be a `DataColumn` so it is unnecessary to do the filtering.

Comment: @Jeff: Mh, in this case you are probably right. I usualy use `OfType` when working on non-generic collections as it won't throw on me in case someone put an unexpected object in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..  How can i assign this to another datatable?

Comment: @Harun, You could create a new `DataTable` and use `ImportRow` to import the filtered rows. Otherwise: Ask a new question and see if someone comes up with a good answer :)

Answer (score -1):

The `Any()` method is in the `System.Linq` namespace. The Method lives in the `Queryable` class

Answer (score -1):

use `system.linq` namespace if framework version is greater than 2

Comment: Clearly he is already using the System.Linq namespace (AsEnumerable).

Answer (score -1):

you should include the following:

```
using System.Linq;
```